# Gimp Fails to Load raw file (NEF) after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, gimp, dist-upgrade

I did and upgrade from (K)ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. It all worked well -- except for Gimp.

Gimp 2.8 works fine but loading a .NEF file (a raw file from Nikon) fails with the message

> Opening '/path/to/file/DSC_2605.NEF' failed:
>
> Procedure 'file-ufraw-load' returned no return values

I have `ufraw` and `gimp-ufraw` installed.

How do I find out what is wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Removing `gimp-ufraw` and installing `gimp-dcraw` helps. However, dcraw is not as nice as ufraw because it doesn't have an interactive user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UFRAW to process a .NEF file first, then Gimp should recognize ufraw as the sub-application to import with.

> To use the UFRaw Gimp plug-in you need first to install Gimp 2.0 or
>   higher. Gimp 2.4 is recommended. If you only plan to use UFRaw's
>   stand-alone tool, there is no need to install Gimp, but the Gimp Tool
>   Kit (GTK+2) is still needed. There is no need to install DCRaw itself
>   since its code is incorporated into UFRaw.

~ http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/Install.html

Comment: "Gimp 2.8 works fine [...]".

Comment: I know, that was a expose from the UFraw web site